# What's a more efficient way to do collisions?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Here's my dilemma

I have 4 walls around the stage of my game, when a player hits these walls I do not want to make an if statement for each and every one of the walls checking if the player is hitting it, so I have created an array to hold the walls, then check if the player is hitting that.  Now, because I am doing this I will not know what the player is actually hitting if he hits something, and I cannot do a check in my array if he's hitting like `[0], [1], [2]` etc because then I'm back to doing the checks if he's hitting specific walls.  The reason I don't want to do that is for the future, when I add more barriers, buildings, and so on.

So my question is, how can I do collision checks, without hard coding checks on specific objects, and giving some sort of value that can be used for the player to respond to, for example if your hitting the top wall and you can figure that out somehow without doing the above, then make it so you can't walk through or something,

```
if (main.playerPosKeeper_mc.hitTestObject(this[main.StageCollisions]))
{
    trace("hit");
}
```

StageCollisions is an array which contains all of my barriers in it.

When the player hits anything in StageCollisions, I cannot just simply subtract from his y value, or x value, because I do not know which object he hit, *but I also do not want to hard code it so that I check if I'm hitting lets say the top barrier, because then why do an array in the first place if I'm just going back to making static if else statements.*

***^^ Refrencing this topic***

[AS3 - How to Cycle States of Character Animations (moving & stopped)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148445/as3-how-to-cycle-states-of-character-animations-moving-stopped)

This has been stumping me for a little while, so help would be greatly appreciated.   It is a hard question to form so I can clarify points if necessary.

Comment: So you want to keep hero clip inside certain rectangle while processing 4 boundary walls in a loop?

Comment: Not necessarily, I'm doing collision checking, and am curious about how I can know which wall the player is hitting, without checking each and every wall I have, and then give the appropriate commands.

My real goal here is to move away from hard coding collision checks with specific objects, as then if I make the game larger, I have to do more checks on specific objects.

The topic I included's response from user Vesper is something I've been trying to work towards but deserves its own topic.

It's possible I might be overthinking this, but yea.

Comment: Also, forgot to mention, I'm doing collision checking once a dpad direction has been clicked, I've been told to use loops before probably by using an event listener that activates every frame, but I think an easier and more efficient way would be to check only when you click the dpad, where it will move you in the direction, check if you hit something, if you hit something, move you back, but then I get the issue above where I do not know what I'm hitting, and I don't want to hard code checks on specific objects for the sake of in the future if I want to add more walls and stuff.

Comment: Not sure I get what you want then. You can have an array of (any number of) walls and in the loop you can find if any of the walls collides with the hero and also find which one wall is to blame if any. Is that what you want?

Comment: Probably a better question for the GameDev stack exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is, how can I do collision checks, without hard coding
>   checks on specific objects, and giving some sort of value that can be
>   used for the player to respond to, for example if your hitting the top
>   wall and you can figure that out somehow without doing the above, then
>   make it so you can't walk through or something

Right, so you want a way to perform a generic collision response. This can be a big topic. The simplest approach is usually to check for a collision after a move, then reverse the move if there's a collision.

Something like this:

```
function movePlayer(movementX:Number, movementY:Number):void {
    var originalX:Number = player.x;
    var originalY:Number = player.y;
    player.x += movementX;
    if (checkCollision()) {
        player.x = originalX;
    }
    player.y += movementY;
    if (checkCollision()) {
        player.y = originalY;
    }
}

function checkCollision():Boolean {
    for each (var wall:MovieClip in walls) {
        if (player.hitTestObject(wall)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This way you could have `checkCollision()` check 4 walls or 50 walls, it doesn't matter. It won't let the player move into them.

This is just a starting point and there are many ways it can break down or be refined.

Answer (score 0):

Some trivial pseudo code for you to study:

```
private function collisionCheck(h:Sprite):Sprite{  // pass the hero Sprite into this function and it will return the wall that it hit
    for each (b:Sprite in blockArray){ // if your array of hit-able objects is called "blockArray"
        if (h.hitTtestObject(b)){ // check the hero Sprite against all objects in the array
            return b;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then, elsewhere in your code (maybe in your gameTick function or gameLoop function or wherever you have your game logic repeating on each frame:

```
private function gameTick():void{
    var objectHit:Sprite = collisionCheck(_myHero); // this will run the collision check function, and return the sprite that the hero collides with;
    if (objectHit != null){
      objectHit.alpha = 0.5; 
      // this will give you a visible representation that your code is indeed working, or not.
    }
}
```

For those moments when your hero isn't colliding with anything, this function will return null.  That's why I first check if objectHit is not null before trying to perform an operation on its alpha value.  Of course, you will do something other than change its alpha value in your project, but this is something I often do (with the alpha) to quickly get a visual confirmation that things are detecting what they are supposed to.

Comment: "Of course, you will do something other than change its alpha value in your project" -- that's what the OP is asking about. ;)

Comment: No, if you read the OPs comments below the post, you'll see he just wants to know how to figure out which wall he hit. He clearly understands the concept of move, check, undo. He just seems to think there is a better way than checking every object in turn through an array, which there really isn't, which is what I was trying to show. Then, if he really needs to know *what* he hit, my code will return that.

Comment: Yeah, this literally returns what object he hit, but his real question is how to do something meaningful with what he hit without resorting to coding different conditions for what got hit. This example doesn't show how to do that at all.

Comment: That may be his goal, but it wasn't his question as I read it. Then again reading comprehension was my lowest score every time I took the ACT, so maybe you're right :)

Comment: Hi, I apologize being unclear about my intention.  It is true that I will want to know which object I am hitting, but this is so I can invoke the correct response (moving up if you're not hitting something, or keeping you stationary to prevent collision, or whatever else I can think of)

I think Aaron's code meets my intention quite well but nonetheless, thank you both for assisting me with this.